# How do I find all Primary ID's in Table A, that have duplicate values in another Column, using criteria from Table B?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

Sorry if the title is confusing, I had a hard time describing my issue.

- Table A: holds Account Numbers (PK) and Social Security numbers
- Table B: holds Account Numbers and Date Account closed.

You can have multiple accounts with the same Social Security Number in Table A.

**Scenario:** I need all Account Numbers from Table A, that have a matching Social Security Number (also in Table A) based on an  Account Number in Table B, but I also need to add a Y/N flag if the Account Number was the specific Account Number from Table B.

**So my train of thought**: I have a list of account numbers from Table B, based on a specific Account Close date:

```
SELECT TableB.acn 
FROM TableB 
WHERE tableB.CloseDate = '2019-06-30'
```

And using a subquery, I can get a list of all the accounts from Table A:

```
SELECT TableA.Acn, TableA.SSN
FROM Table A
WHERE table A.SSN in (SELECT TableA.SSN 
                      FROM TableA 
                      INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ACN = TableB.ACN
                                WHERE tableB.closeDate = '2019-06-30')
```

But here is where I'm stumped, because I don't know how to

- Add a flag to the list to show that the Account Number is the Account Number from Table B,
- Remove all the other Accounts from Table A that do not have a duplicate SSN.

Any help would be great. I will be monitoring heavily for the next hour or so in case anyone has any follow up questions.

Thanks for your help SO.

Comment: *I need all Account Numbers from Table A, that have a matching Social Security Number* so what is the point of the flag since all the Account Numbers that will be selected from Table A will also exist in Table B?

Comment: Hey Forpas, all of the account numbers from A won't be in B -- B has less account numbers than A. I am trying to find the other account numbers from A via A's SSN field, that match the account numbers from B. Hope that clarifies

Comment: So you want all accounts from A even if they do not have a match of SSN in B and set a flag Y for the matching ones and N for the non matching?

Comment: Yes, the goal is to find accounts in A with duplicate SSN's, from a list of accounts from B. Essentially finding all Accounts in A with matching SSNs, that only exist in B with the Date criteria if that makes sense -- and a flag to show which one of the account numbers is the account number from B

Comment: So if Joe has an account in B that meets the criteria, you want a list of all his other accounts in A with a note indicating which one met the criteria?

Comment: Yep, thats essentially it Mike!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a flag on whether or not there is a match, then I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT A.Acn, A.SSN,
       (CASE WHEN B.ACN IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as b_flag
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B
     ON A.ACN = B.ACN AND B.closeDate = '2019-06-30'
```

Comment: I think SSN is in A not B.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b5a18/5)

Data

```
create table acct_and_ssn (
acct int,
ssn varchar(255) 
);

insert into acct_and_ssn (acct, ssn)
values 
(1, 123456789),
(2, 123456789),
(3, 123456789),
(4, 223456789),
(5, 223456789),
(6, 333456789),
(7, 333456789),
(8, 333456789),
(9, 444567889),
(10, 444567889)
;


create table acct_and_date (
acct int,
mydate date 
);

insert into acct_and_date (acct, mydate)
values 
(2, '06/30/2019'),
(6, '06/30/2019'),
(9, '04/12/2019')
;
```

Accounts 2 and 6 meet our close criteria.  The SSNs associated with 2 and 6 are also associated with accounts 1, 3, 7, and 8.

```
with flagged_accounts_cte (acct, ssn) as
(
select 
a.acct, 
a.ssn

from 
acct_and_ssn a inner join acct_and_date b
on a.acct = b.acct and b.mydate = '06/30/2019'
)
select
c.acct,
c.ssn, 
(case
when c.acct = d.acct then 1 else 0 
 end) as myflag
from 
acct_and_ssn c
inner join flagged_accounts_cte d
on c.ssn = d.ssn
```

Create a subquery (here done as a CTE) that ids the closed accounts and then marry that back up to the table with the SSNs to find the other accounts.

Gives us

`acct   ssn myflag
1   123456789   0
2   123456789   1
3   123456789   0
6   333456789   1
7   333456789   0
8   333456789   0`